# Network connectivity checking in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to check network available or not.
But in my emulator it always shows `connected` (after disconnecting internet also)

Is there any mistake in my code.I am connecting with **wifi**.

*Code:*

```
public class AndroidConnectivityActivity extends Activity
{
Button checkBtn;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
      checkBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

      checkBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
       public void onClick(View v)
       {
        if(isInternetOn())
        {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not connected",
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       }});
     }

     public final boolean isInternetOn()
     {
      ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService
      (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      if ((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
        ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
        ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
        ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
      {
       return true;
      }

      else if ((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED)
        || (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED))
      {
       return false;
      }

      return false;
     }
    }
```

Comment: There is no problem with your code. But How did u actually disconnect the internet?

Comment: Try to test your Code in Airplane Mode.

Comment: just to switch off wifi or lan connection

Comment: i think you are missing the permission in manifest file            
<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: no i have already give that permission

Comment: have you tested it on any device?

Comment: your code works fine....

Comment: NO i am testing it only on emulator..how your running this. i am getting "Connected" only after switch off wifi and lan connection

Comment: i used the same code... put my emulator on airplane mode and it showed me a toast showing NOT CONNECTED

Comment: ok tell me from where i can put it on airplane mode

Comment: goto settings  the click the wireless& networks  and then first checkbox(Airplane mode)... this will disable all wireless connections

Comment: it means my code is fine and i can show it to my seniors...haha

Comment: have you used DDMS's emulator control???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use below code

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        boolean isInternetAvailable = false;

        try
        {  
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(networkInfo != null && (networkInfo.isConnected()))
            {
                isInternetAvailable  = true;
            }    
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // Do Nothing
        }

        return isInternetAvailable;
    }
```

and also try on real device

use code in Activity onCreate Method like

```
if(isInternetAvailable(this))
{
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "internet available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
}
else
{
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "internet not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
}
```

Required manifest permission

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: can u show Toast message with our code..to know exactly whats going on

Comment: see edited code..and don't forget to set Internet permission in Manifest File

Comment: off course buddy. I never post non working code in any forum.

Comment: actully showing red line under isInternetAvailable(this))...what should i pass instead of this

Comment: you need to pass context of Activity. Means if your activity name is MainActivity then pass MainActivity .this

Comment: i am using your code same as it is ..but giving error .many red lines are here

Comment: if you are using Eclispe with Window machine then pres 'ctrl+shift' then 'O' to import required package. If you are using other system then manually import required package

Comment: add again see edited code, I have mention required permission

Comment: thanks vivek for your replies ..my code is fine just problem with switch off wifi and all

Comment: Okay..fine but in your code you are using connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() and connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() without chceking value of connec.getNetworkInfo(1), maybe its return null then you will get NullPointer Exception. Some people facing this issue.

Comment: that's the reason I am using this code..and if you see given answer lot of people provide the same answer like me.

Comment: @H.S - vivek has proposed you the good code.. So mark the answer as correct if it is helpful to you... As per me the code is absolutely right..

Answer (score 2):

Use mehod shoen below

```
public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

and in manifest set permission  as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
private boolean getOnlineState() {
        ConnectivityManager myConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo myNetworkInfo = myConnectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (myNetworkInfo != null
                && myNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
            return true;
        return false;

    }
```

and btw:

```
if ((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
  {
   return true;
  }

  else if ((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED)
    || (connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED))
  {
   return false;
  }

  return false;
 }
```

is the same like:

```
    if ((connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING)
    ||(connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
         return true;
         return false;
```

Yous should try such hardwareoperations on a real phone rather then the emulator.